# DbiSchedule control on Escape key click exception is thrown cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dbi

I am using DbiSchedule control in a form, on escape key click i am closing the form. Which throws an error ObjectDisposed exception and stackTrace is as follows :

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Handle.get()  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphicsInternal()  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphics()  Unknown
    Dbi4.dll!Dbi.WinControl.DbiListControl.OnKeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)
```

No exception on ALT+F4, form closes successfully.
Any ideas what is causing the exception and how I might go about fixing it? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding solves the exception:

```
public class MydbiSchedule : Dbi.WinControl.Schedule.dbiSchedule
    {      

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Escape)
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }

    }
```